# how to split comma separated values in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote a SQL query with the inner join. But it has 3 columns and the 3 columns are included comma-separated values. So I need to split these 3 columns values as a row.

How can I do this?

[image: Query]

Comment: What version of SQL Server? SQL Server 2016 and later support the [string_split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) table-valued function.

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble!

Comment: Not all of us has that luxury @jarlh. Often we end up having to patch on top of other developers poor database design.

Comment: A tip here may stop OP doing the same thing.

Comment: Please show the results that you want.  It is not clear.  Also, *text tables* are much easier to read than images.

Comment: Do you always have exactly 3 values separated with comma?